# What format and encoding does iPhone save video clips in?

Tags: iphone, video, encoding, file

Using the default Photo/Video application. Tried to find any info regarding this on Apple's web site with no success. Does anyone have the specs on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[h.264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264) encoded video, [AAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding) audio. Both standards of [MPEG 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4).

Comment: Thanks Jason. I see that the files are saved in .mov instead of the more common .mp4. Is this configurable in any way?

Comment: No, you can’t change that.